WPF uses more RAM if RenderOptions is set to Hardware
I realized my application takes around 300 Mb of working memory. Before even attempting to troubleshoot it, I opened up a blank WPF project in Visual Studio 2022 and started it. BAM! ~270 Mb of working memory taken.
I then started to search the reason as to why this is happening, and it turns out that the main reason behind it is the capabilities of the machine that is executing the application. This is influenced by the Tier property. You can find more about it here. Upon further investigation I came across a property called RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode (more can be found here). This property takes an enumeration value, and two possible values are:

Default - The WPF rendering is in hardware, if possible; software otherwise.
SoftwareOnly - The WPF rendering is in software only.

If I set this property to SoftwareOnly then the memory taken is ~50 Mb. If you look at the Default description, then it is logical that WPF engine chose hardware rendering before and setting it to SoftwareOnly yielded different results.
Why does hardware rendering take so much more RAM than software rendering?
EDIT
Although this question is similar to an existing question that can be found here, it is fundamentally different because this question is dealing with working memory and the other one is dealing with CPU utilization.

The short answer is probably your drivers done it.  What gpu are you using?

Hardware rendering means that it depends on your hardware. As for example if you have dedicated GRAM or it is mixed, how drivers are handling the requests and many other aspects. Note that the Hardware rendering is typically good to reduce the CPU load, which in most cases can be abottleneck

I have found the issue, and it is as Andy has suggested in the comments of the question. However, the issue becomes increasingly interesting, and these are my findings.
First of all, let me say that the laptop I have is Dell Precision 3581. It has a dedicated GPU (NVidia) and integrated GPU in form of an Intel Iris XE. As Andy suggested there seems to be a problem with drivers but the fix for this problem is being "ping-ponged" between Microsoft and Intel.
If I set RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode to SoftwareOnly, then hardware acceleration is out of the picture and RAM usage goes to normal. Otherwise, WPF will use Intel Iris XE with bad drivers. If I go to Device Manager and disable Intel Iris XE then the only GPU left to use is NVidia. In this case the RAM usage ALSO goes back to normal.
Now, the interesting part about the case where integrated graphics is used is that if I have only one display, RAM usage is low(er). It is still high, and it is obvious there is an issue, but it is lower. However, I have 3 displays connected and due to this the RAM usage is extremely high.
This is the RAM usage I wrote down:

NVidia on any number of displays - 80 Mb
Intel Iris XE 1 display - 200 Mb
Intel Iris XE 3 displays - 400 Mb

I chose not to take any action at the moment but if the application is not intensive with graphics or animations, I think SoftwareOnly options would fix it. Instead, I will wait for Intel to fix the drivers.
